# How can I do the Showing 1 to 3 of 12 entries in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I want to add the "Showing 1 to 3 of 12 entries" on the bottom of my table. I want to change "Showing 1 to 3..." when the user clicks the next or previous button or the 1234 number of the pagination. It depends on the number of the first rows and last row on the table. For example, when the user clicks the next or 2 it will look like this "Showing 4 to 6 of 12 entries". I want to show only the "previous 123 next" instead of "previous 1234 next" to my pagination. This is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wbshyrn2/4/

```
Showing {{customers.length - 11}} to {{customers.length - 9}} of {{customers.length}} entries
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computed property could be used to calculate the start and end indexes.

```
    maxBtns: function(){
      return Math.ceil(this.customers.length / 3) > 3 ? 3 : Math.ceil(this.customers.length / 3);
    },
    positionText: function () {
      var endIndex = this.currentPage * this.perPage,
        startIndex = ((this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage) + 1;

      return "Showing "+startIndex+ " to "+ (endIndex>this.customers.length? this.customers.length :endIndex)  + " of " + this.customers.length;
    }
```

For showing a maximum of 3 buttons you can use the computed property in the button v-for binding.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-group toggle float-right" data-toggle="buttons" v-for="num in maxBtns" @click="pagination(num)">{{num}}</button>
```

Comment: how can I limit the number of pagination to only "previous 123 next" instead of "previous 1234 next"? I want to hide the 4 in my pagination.

Comment: So when you are on page 4, do you still want to show "previous 123 next" or something like "previous .. 234 next"

Comment: I want the first one sir -> "previous 123 next"